# JQuery .change event only triggered when data entered, but not if fields preloaded

Tags: jquery

I want to enable a button when certain fields are populated.

am currently using jquery .change method:

```
$('#Balance, #Period').change(function() {
   var balance = $('#Balance').val();
   var period = $('Period').val;

   if (balance != "" & period != "") {
      $('#btnNext').attr('disabled', false);
   } else {
      $('#btnNext').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

but this only works if the user has entered something, I want this to occur when all fields have data (ie: at the time the page loads).

Comment: Any fiddle or code would be appreciated.

Comment: Because preloading will happen before binding change event with elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 'Change' event will only fire when the data is updated so wont fire on page load. 
To do that you'd need to fire the event manually. i.e.

```
$('#Balance, #Period').change(function() {
   var balance = $('#Balance').val();
   var period = $('Period').val;

   if (balance != "" & period != "") {
      $('#btnNext').attr('disabled', false);
   } else {
      $('#btnNext').attr('disabled', true);
   }
}

$(function(){
    $('#Balance, #Period').trigger('change'); 
    // fire the change even when doc ready
});
```

OR have the main code as a separate function and call that.

```
$('#Balance, #Period').change(updateThings);

function updateThings(){
    var balance = $('#Balance').val();
       var period = $('Period').val;

       if (balance != "" & period != "") {
          $('#btnNext').attr('disabled', false);
       } else {
          $('#btnNext').attr('disabled', true);
       }
}

$(function(){
    updateThings();
});
```

Comment: That works better - the problem now is that #Period is a lister, populated using `$('#Period').val('@Model.PaymentPeriod');` - populated by Razor on page generation, and doesnt fire any events.

Answer (score 0):

You should put code you launch on change in separate function and call it before you bind change. Triggering additional change may cause other things to launch (if you have binded other change somewhere on those elements). So it should look like:

```
$(function() {
    var $balance = $('#Balance');
    var $period  = $('#Period');
    var $btn     = $('#btnNext');

    var updateBtn = function updateBtn() {
        var isEnabled = $balance.val() && $period.val();
        $btn.attr('disabled', !isEnabled);
    };

    updateBtn();
    $balance.add($period).on('change', updateBtn);
});
```